# How to group by the value of the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pivot-table

I have these 2 df which are basically the same but in df1, the values are the amount of the payment of the respective customer and the another is the customers status for that period(the columns 1,2,3,4 are periods):

df1:

```
customer|1|2|3|4
x       |2|5|5|5
y       | |5|5|5
z       |5|5|5|
```

df2:

```
customer|1|2|3|4
x       |N|E|E|E
y       | |N|E|E
z       |N|E|C|-
```

I want to group by the status which is the values of the df2 to be like:

```
Status  1 |2 |3 |4
N        7|5 |  |
E         |10|10|10
C         |  |5 |
```

I used to group the status count using

```
df2.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

but now, instead of `count` the values, I want to `SUM` the value of the respective dataframe `DF1`

Comment: Can you change your data generation so that I can make sure that I understand the DataFrame? I'm not sure why you have missing values and a '-' in your data. Are those supposed to NaNs? Does the following: `df1 = pandas.DataFrame({1:[2,0,5], 2:[5,5,5], 3:[5,5,5], 4:[5,5,0]}, index=['x', 'y', 'z'])` represent the DataFrame you are working on?

Comment: These are pivotted tables I see. Is there a way to share the original table which you used?

Comment: the empty spaces and '-' are NaN. actually it doesn't represent. it is just an example

Comment: one example of these 2 dataframes
https://i.imgur.com/R1L9L0A.png

Comment: You have your data in `jupyter notebook`. Please do `print(df1.head(10))` & `print(df2.head(10))` and copy paste the output of that in your question. That output is copyable for us and we can use that to answer your question. Thanks

Comment: it's similar to a pivot_table but actually I split the months between the periods in which the customer STARTED TO PAY to the period that it STOPED TO PAY. in the original DATABASE is basically a column with the date that he started to pay and another with the end of payment, but it's not only that. this is just part of a bigger FUNCTION that returns a json to our front end by the arguments of period, date, kind of period like (month,  year, quarter) so the function is always generating those DFs when executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As so often, this seems difficult, because you have your DataFrames in a weird shape. If you first [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) them, it becomes easy: just [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) them, [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your quantities of interest and sum them (and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) again if you want to display it in that format):

```
df1m = df1.melt(id_vars='customer', var_name='period', value_name='amount')
df2m = df2.melt(id_vars='customer', var_name='period', value_name='status')
dfm = df1m.merge(df2m)
res = dfm.groupby(['status', 'period'])['amount'].sum().reset_index()
res.pivot_table(index='status', columns='period')

#period      1     2     3     4
#status                         
#C         NaN   NaN   5.0   NaN
#E         NaN  10.0  10.0  10.0
#N         7.0   5.0   NaN   NaN
```

To show what melt does: it unpivots the DataFrame, so you have one row per observation (customer, period) that has the amount/status

```
df1m
#    customer period  amount
#0   x             1     2.0
#1   y             1     NaN
#2   z             1     5.0
#3   x             2     5.0
#4   y             2     5.0
#5   z             2     5.0
#6   x             3     5.0
#7   y             3     5.0
#8   z             3     5.0
#9   x             4     5.0
#10  y             4     5.0
11  z             4     NaN
```

Comment: I know it's weird but it was perfect for the the purpose i was using that is group by the count, and now i'm trying to reuse this and i also and still think it is better than the original database

Comment: Sure, it's fine for visualisation. However, with manipulation, often times you will want to use Tidy Data: https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf. Anyway, hope it helped

Comment: but amazing i didn't know that melt method is very impressive!